# añadir filas a un datatable en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatables

Estoy tratando de añadir varias filas a un datatable desde un array en vb .Net

Este es mi código:

```
For j = 0 To totalRows
    For k = 0 To totalCols
        If (IsDBNull(ArrLoadLDT(j, k)) Or ArrLoadLDT(j, k) = "") Then
            row(dt.Columns(k).ColumnName) = ""
        Else
            row(dt.Columns(k).ColumnName) = ArrLoadLDT(j, k).ToString()
        End If
    Next
    dt.Rows.Add(row)
Next
```

Me deja añadir la primera fila pero cuando intenta añadir la segunda fila me muestra el siguiente error:

> This row already belongs to this table.

He estado mirando en diferentes sitios y muestran la misma estructura para añadir.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Necesitamos ver donde defines `row`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
  For j = 0 To totalRows
    row = dt.NewRow()
    For k = 0 To totalCols
        If (IsDBNull(ArrLoadLDT(j, k)) Or ArrLoadLDT(j, k) = "") Then
            row(dt.Columns(k).ColumnName) = ""
        Else
            row(dt.Columns(k).ColumnName) = ArrLoadLDT(j, k).ToString()
        End If
    Next
    dt.Rows.Add(row)
  Next
```

Comment: Perfect Javier, me ha dejado sin ningún problema. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, Un saludo

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Revisa tambien [answer]. Aunque esto solucione el problema planteado, en [es.so] se pide que una respuesta no sea sólo código. Debes explicar cual era el problema del OP y porqué este código soluciona el problema.Un saludo y bienvenido de nuevo.